# Константная ссылка на объект. Корректный термин на английском.

Tags: терминология

У меня есть особый вид переменных, значение которым можно присвоить лишь однажды. При присваивании объекта, присвается ссылка на него.

Но при этом состояние объекта можно менять. Constant object подойдёт или нет?

Comment: Просто любопытно, в каком ЯП можно изменять свойства объекта по константной ссылке? оО

Comment: Объект у вас обычный, ссылку на него можно растиражировать из вашей константной ссылки.

Comment: Например в Ruby. Там всё что начинается с большой буквы -- константа:
<pre>
> class A
>   attr_accessor :moped
>   end
 => nil 
> AConst = A.new
 => #<A:0xa4794d8> 
> AConst.moped = 1
 => 1 
> AConst.moped = 2
 => 2 
> AConst.moped
 => 2 
> AConst = A.new
(irb):9: warning: already initialized constant AConst
 => #<A:0xa15a6f8> 

</pre>

Comment: Или, например, в Java. Может и назвать также, final :)

Comment: @niXman по константное ссылке ни в одном языке нельзя менять свойства объекта. Именно в этом суть термина «константная». Именно по этой причине автор разыскивает другой термин и поднял здесь этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В теории языков программирования это называется [*name binding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding), иными словами - сопоставление конкретного объекта с именем, в отличие от переменной (variable), которая является слотом в памяти, куда можно поместить значение объекта (если это, скажем, число), или ссылку на него.

Если же вы просто решили создать некий класс-контейнер, который можно проинициализировать некоторым значением, но нельзя присвоить другое, и решаете как его назвать, то можно воспользоваться термином "ячейка" (*cell*), как это [сделано](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Cell.html) в языке Scala:

```
scala> val container = new Cell(256)
container: Cell[Int] = Cell(256)

scala> container.elem
res1: Int = 256

scala> container.elem = 257
<console>:6: error: reassignment to val
       container.elem = 257
                      ^
```

Из примера видно, что контейнер Cell содержит некоторый элемент (elem), но изменить его нельзя. В то же время, если при создании в Cell "положить", к примеру, массив, то элементы этого массива законно можно изменять. Можно также использовать еще более говорящее название *ImmutableCell* или *PersistentCell*.

В конце-концов, можно, не мудрствуя лукаво, просто использовать канонический термин *value*, как противоположность variable. Авторы Scala так и делают (обратите внимание на ключевые слова: val (value) и var (variable)):

```
scala> val x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> var y = 10
y: Int = 10

scala> y = 20
y: Int = 20

scala> x = 20
<console>:6: error: reassignment to val
       x = 20
         ^
```

Comment: Великолепный ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы назвал **immutable reference**.

По-моему, очень подходящий термин.

По крайней мере, это распространённая терминология. Довольно естественно и общепринято, что когда говорят о `const` (например, ссылке или списке), то состояние внутренних объектов менять нельзя, а если коллекция `immutable`, то из этого не следует, что содержащиеся в ней объекты тоже `immutable`.

*P.S. Ой, внимательнее прочитал ответ, который самый длинный. Там тоже в конце предлагают `immutable`… По-моему, отличный и обоснованный вариант.*

Comment: Похоже тоже подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы назвал ConstReference, раз ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

А что за область? Какой язык программирования?
Например, в C++ Const Reference будет подразумевать невозможность изменить объект:

```
const Object& obj_ref = obj;
```

так мы скажем, что obj_ref - ссылка на obj, но по этой ссылке изменить obj будет нельзя.

Если же просто Reference, то будет подразумеваться, что ссылка присвоена единожды, в самом начале, а вот сам объект, на который идёт ссылка, изменять можно.

Так что в терминах C++ - просто Reference.

Comment: Язык программирования Ruby.

Comment: Я для себя решил этот вопрос: просто буду называть constant. Но как это называется корректно и общепринято -- пока вопрос открытый.

Comment: Это, кстати, верно подмечено, что в терминах C это будет просто reference. Проблема в том, что в ссылочно-ориентированных языках (которых уже, наверное, большинство, в том числе Ruby) немного другое понятие ссылки. Отсюда-то и возникает необходимость уточнять термин.